# Writing a file that is similar to a CSV file

Tags: csvhelper

I need to parse/write a LEDES 1998B file.  It is very similar to a CSV except that:
1.  Instead of commas separating fields, PIPE characters (|) do.
2.  instead of \n or \r\n ending a line, []\r\n does.

I have found that I can use:

```
        var Configuration = new CsvHelper.Configuration.Configuration();
        Configuration.Delimiter = "|";
```

to set the delimiter.

How do I set the NewLine/EndOfRecord character?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set it on the particular `TextWriter` that you pass to `CsvWriter`

```cs
var records = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "one" },
    new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "two" },
};

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
{
    writer.NewLine = "[]\r\n";
    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "|";

    csv.WriteRecords(records);
}
```

I just realized that reading is going to be a lot more difficult.  You can't set `Newline` on the `TextReader`.  You could potentially rewrite the `CsvParser`, but that is a lot of work.  Here is a possible workaround, but it is not as flexible. It assumes you know what the last column is and that your headers don't have "[]" in them.

```cs
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{

    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "|";
    csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (header, index) => header.Replace("[]", "");
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(new FooMap());

    var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NewId { get; set; }
}

public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        AutoMap();
        Map(m => m.NewId).TypeConverter<RemoveEndBracketsConverter>();
    }
}


public class RemoveEndBracketsConverter : Int32Converter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if (text.Length >= 2 && text.Substring(text.Length - 2) == "[]")
        {
            text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 2);
        }
        return base.ConvertFromString(text, row, memberMapData);
    }
}
```